# Laravel: how to pass id to a modal for editing

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-8

In Laravel 8 app, I'm using a model to add items. In my view file, I'm doing it as follows

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-item-modal" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-create"> Create new item</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="add-item-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="loginmodal-container">
        .... <form comes here>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As said, this works for adding items.

I now also want to use a similar logic for editing items. So I have added the following on my page

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-auction-modal" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-warning"><em class="fa fa-pencil"></em></a>

<div class="modal fade" id="add-item-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="loginmodal-container">
        .... <form comes here>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem however is that I need to pass the id of the current item (I wish to edit) to the modal box so that the modal can display the values for the item I wish to update.

How can this be done?

Comment: The `id` attribute of your modal does not fit the `data-target`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use`data`attribute to pass some data into Bootstrap modal.

Buttons in the loop

```
@foreach()

     <a data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{$member->name}}" href="#UserDialog" class="user_dialog">Details</a>

@endforeach
```

Bootstrap model

```
<div class="modal hide" id="UserDialog">
 <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>some content</p>
        <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And little JavaScript

```
$(document).on("click", ".user_dialog", function () {
     var UserName = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #user_name").val( UserName );
});
```

That's it

Little demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/Au9tc/6247/